# Xcode Time Profiler: flat view

Tags: xcode, profiling, xcode-instruments

Is there a way to view profiling data as a flat list in Xcode's Time Profiler instrument (one line per function/method)?

I am profiling a piece of code (iOS app) that uses a lot of indirect recursion: it walks JSON objects recursively and maps them to Core Data, so I end up with *huge* call trees.

I tried using the Flatten Recursion option but it didn't quite help.

Does Time Profiler have something like that? Perhaps there is an alternative tool?